# How to save multiple initialized record with one save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Take it as example.

```
new_array = []

Country.all do |c|
  g = c
  c = c.clone
  c.country_name = "kkk"
  new_array << c
end
```

At this point my new_array containing multiple records ..
How may i store all the values with one save or create ?
Any other better way ?